# Equal-width and equal-depth binning, using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, data-mining, binning

I have wound several examples of equal-mean binning, using `scipy`, but I wondering if it is possible to use library for equal-width or -depth binning.

Actually, I'm fine using other libraries, not only `scipy`

Comment: I can't answer your question. I've just noticed that rapidminer has some interesting options on these lines: https://docs.rapidminer.com/studio/operators/cleansing/binning/discretize_by_frequency.html.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist trying out RapidMiner for this purpose. I created a set of random, Gaussian deviates with this script.

```
>>> import random
>>> with open('gaussian.txt', 'w') as gaussian:
...     for n in range(100):
...         _ = gaussian.write(str(random.gauss(0,1))+'\n')
```

I used the free version of RapidMiner Studio.

I loaded the data by following the `Add Data` button. Then I 'designed' my calculation in the 'Process' pane, like this.

[image: design]

To get this you drag-and-drop the 'Retrieve gaussian' dataset from the left pane near the top, and the 'Discretize' from the lower left pane. I found that a search form made it easy to find the latter item using 'binning' as a search term.

I set 'size of bins' for 'Discretize' and connected two components with each other and the 'res' which seems to mean 'output'.

The results included this information.

[image: binning]

Answer (score -1):

Don't expect everything to require a library.

Both bombings can be implemented in 1 or 2 lines of Python code if you think about them for a minute. It probably takes you longer to find/install/study a library than to just write this code yourself.